# Unittest for ORM-related objects

Tags: unit-testing, orm, mocking

I am working in a Python project where I have some classes that extend from another that gives them an "ORM Layer" to call it in some way. These objects are persistent in the DB when their attributes change.

The big problem comes when I want to test the logics of these objects, it really gets close to impossible to mock everything and I'm going nuts.

Is there any strategy or directives to test this kind of situation? Thanks.

Comment: which ORM framework is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic strategy is not to test the database or other frameworks. Assume that they work.

I don't know which persistance / ORM framework is used. But a good strategy here is [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch): Instead of mocking the framework, you overwrite methods in your test that try to access the database with empty ones:

```
def nop(*args, **kw): pass

ORFramework.BaseObject.messThingsUp = nop
```

where `messThingsUp` is a method of the class `BaseObject` that you want to get rid of.

Comment: I was having problems to do that because of different kind of methods: static, classmethod or method bound to the object. I used a `mock` from the python mock library to get rid of the base class method. Although not exactly what you said, it helped me to think. Thanks.